# Django website that use webcrawling

Tags: python, django, django-templates, web-crawler

I made in python a webcrawler, and I want to make Django website to display the results of the crawling, can I do it? for example: the crawler enter to "https://stackoverflow.com/questions" and take the questins of the first page and display it on the website(maybe on the tamplate of Django).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I just re-read your question and it looks like you're already doing the scraping? You should implement that functionality into a Django site and then yes of course you can display it.

Yes you can do it. A great combination for web scraping with django is using the python requests library (which I'm guessing you're using) and[Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). I've used this combination in a few different projects and I've been happy with it.

Another popular option uses the python Scrapy library and combines it into a django app called [django-dynamic-scraper](http://django-dynamic-scraper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html).

Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I read that you can't use python code inside the template, so how could I connect the python code to the Django. Where can I study this?(website/youtube etc.)

Comment: It seems you miss a lot of basic stuff. If you use Django you must know that you find the [documentation on the Django website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/). Just follow the tutorial.